# there is no developers license on this computer

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2012, licensing

I'm trying to following the instructions at  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-deploy-your-windows-store-app-to-surface-rt-for-testing.aspx. I have an old WinRT surface tablet and a windows 8 notebook computer with Visual Studio Versions 2010, 2012 & 2013.
Apparently, I need run powershell in administrator mode on my tablet and issue the following command:

```
   Get-WindowsDeveloperLicence
```

Well this works OK on my notebook where it pops up a dialog but not on the tablet. On the tablet it says

```
 Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense  : There is no developer license on this computer.
```

So I tried

```
  Show-WindowsDeveloperLicense
```

and again this works fine on the notebook book but on the table it says

```
  Show-WindowsDevelopersLicense : The term 'Show-WindowsDeveloperLicense' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

So I'm confused. I assume I write "Hello World" as a windows store app and deploy it to my tablet to try it out. Apparently it won't run on the tablet until I get a license? How do I get a license? This tablet is too small to run Visual Studio.

Thanks

Siegfried

Answer (score 0):

The command to get a developer license is

```
Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
```

Which, when run in Powershell, will open a dialog box with information on how to get a developer license.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj657535.aspx

Comment: Arg! My fault! My original web page was correct and I did not type it correctly! Thanks for your help.